# Privacy vs monitoring cyber crime

Tags: legal, crime

So , how does the police find/monitor criminals' actions (eavesdropping) that do cyber crime(pornography , drug trafficking etc..) without breaking their privacy, and succesfully catch em and provide evidence for the court.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: If police start monitoring someone they break their annonimity and their unlinkability  they have with  their actions. What methods should they use to monitor the criminal without breaking their annonimity and unlinkability.

Comment: Sorry but you are asking a question related to legal requirements which are different for every single country and sometimes even region. Also why would the police car about not breaking their privacy?

Comment: It's a project for my school , thats why I'm asking.

Police would care because thats the law, which means police cant enter your house without a reason and take your hard drives.

Comment: A common criticism of cyber policing is that the police regularly do invade user's privacy. While real world searches have legal protections, these are sometimes bypassed for cyber searches.

Comment: They can, with a [warrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_(law)). This is indeed too broad and there might be many ways to catch criminals in their act (red-handed), or post-festum. It usually involves gathering evidence remotely, like inspecting access logs or actively trapping (honeynets), then seizing their equipment with a proper warrant and analyzing them with various forensic tools for further, non-circumstantial evidence that would hold in courts. Exact methods would substantially differ by each jurisdiction though, and which methods are permissible by law and which aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The police in most (if not all) countries obeys to various investigation laws and clear legal frameworks that determine what they are authorized to do, how, when, etc.

Usually to wiretap a communication, a police officer has to obtain the approval of a judiciary authority (e.g. an independant judge).

There might be exceptions to those rules in case of specific investigations and/or when there is urgency to act (e.g. terrorism, or a crime that is going to be commited soon), but again those cases are well defined in the law to prevent abuse/mis-use by the authorities.

All the administrative procedures, paperwork, approvals, authorizations etc. have to be stricly followed in order for the evidence to be received by the court.